# Using the statement "at most one" in propositional logic and in horns clause

Tags: propositional-calculus

I am studying for my exams and I am having some trouble understanding how to write the below statements in:

1. Propositional logic
2. Horn clause.

> A. Customer chooses Converse shoes
> B. Customer chooses Adidas shoes
>
> The customer can choose at most one brand of shoes.

Here is what I have come up with:

$(A \lor B) \land \lnot(A \land B)$

Is the above correct? And how would this be represented in Horn clause?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic statement doesn't match the problem statement - you give a formula for **exactly** one. For **at most** one, write:

$$\lnot(A \land B)$$

Using de Morgan's laws again, the new statement becomes:

$$\lnot A \lor \lnot B$$

which is a Horn clause (in fact it is a [goal](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Goal.html) - no positive literal).

Comment: is there a possible way of writing the above as horns clause?